# How can I display wp_link_pages before a shortcode, if it is used, or display after content?

Tags: filters, shortcode, wp-link-pages

I have the following shortcode in my content

```
[src]<a href="#">Some Link</a>, <a href="#">Some Other Link</a>[/src]
```

My post structure looks like this:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
<?php wp_link_pages();?>
```

If that shortcode is being used in the content, I'd like for wp_link_pages to appear before it, if not, I would like it to display after the content. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If the shortcode is present, you want `wp_list_pages` to display before all of the post content or just before the shortcode?

Comment: If the shortcode is present, I want wp_list_pages to display before that shortcode. Haven't tried anything yet, I've been looking for a solution. I figure I need to a function that will check if the shortcode is being used in the post, and place the wp_list_pages before it, else, place wp_list_pages after the_content. And I understand that I'll need to use a filter to check for the shortcode before it is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
// your shortcode callback
function your_sc_callback($atts,$content) {
  $content = wp_list_pages(array('echo'=>false)).$content;
  define('YOUR_SC_RAN',true);
  return $content;
}
```

Now, in your theme template after the content prints

```
if (!defined('YOUR_SC_RAN')) {
  wp_list_pages();
}
```

Or, you could do ...

```
function append_list_pages($content) {
  return $content.wp_list_pages(array('echo'=>false));
}
add_filter('the_content','append_list_pages',100);
```

And your shortcode callback would be ...

```
function your_sc_callback($atts,$content) {
  $content = wp_list_pages(array('echo'=>false)).$content;
  remove_filter( 'the_content','append_list_pages',100 );
  return $content;
}
```

Both or these are untested, so no guarantees, but I think either should work.

Comment: No luck. wp list pages doesn't work from inside a shortcode function. Also, instead of echo, we have to use return I'm pretty sure.

Alternatively, is there a way to pull out the content that is returned from the shortcode, and append it after the wp_list_pages.

Maybe if I create a global variable to hold the output, then echo that after the wp_list_pages... though I'm not entirely sure how to even do that.

Comment: Yes. Probably should return. I am somewhat concerned about other `the_content` filters breaking the markup. I see no reason `wp_list_pages` shouldn't work in a shortcode : http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/post-template.php#L813

Comment: Actually it is being output! However, it's not in the correct position, it is appearing above the actual post.

Comment: Nevermind, I reviewed your code again, and I had implemented it incorrectly. It works now! Thank you.

Comment: Okay, ran into another issue.

So I'm using <!--next page--> in the post.
And I have [src]...[/src] after the <!--next page -->

As a result, the wp_list_pages runs fine on the last page, but it isn't being called on the pages where the src is not available.

I guess the functionality should actually be, if there is no src shortcode, run wp_list_pages. Thoughts?

Comment: Which option are you using? I think the first version, but not the second, should probably work in the case you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty  where you want to put the wp_list_pages and  and after all of that, use jQuery (html function) to move the content frome #from to #destionation.

Comment: Please supply some example code as well as the description of what is does